# How can Select model of all Child and parent when I have only child-id and reverse?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, lambda

I have 2 tables

```
    public long id {get;set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }       
    public long? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> SubCategories { get; set; }
```

and

```
    public long id {get;set;}
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public long? CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
```

category:

```
ID name           parent id
1 Electronic 
2 Mobile            1
3 laptop            1
```

I want when user search in category for example 1

I show all product with this category and with its parent

I wrote

```
 models = models.Where(i => i.Category.SubCategories.Select(i => i.Id).Contains(catid));
```

but it's not correct code

Comment: `but it's not correct code` because? We don't know without knowing what your sample input is and what the expected output is

Comment: I want to show parent when i have child id
for example when i search 1 
my code show all  electronic category.

Comment: Perhaps `models.Where(i => i.Id == catid || i.Category.SubCategories.Any(i => i.Id == catid))` Are there deeper levels of sub-sub-categories?